# PlaySound cannot play two async sounds

Tags: c++, winapi

For my game, I  use the PlaySound function in the Windows API for my music and sound. But when I tried to play a sound while my music is playing, the music just halts, and I only get to hear the sound.

I play my music like so:

```
PlaySound("sounds\\title.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP | SND_FILENAME | SND_NOSTOP);
```

And then I play my "menu-choose sound":

`PlaySound("sounds\\choose.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME);`

Is there anyway I can make the music play, and hear the sound while the music plays?

Answer (score 3):

PlaySound API doesn't support mixing two or more sounds. You should use a more advanced API, for example DirectSound or OpenAL.